# Views menu options moved to top of structure menu, no obvious way to move them

Tags: routes

I had a funny thing happen, where the views menu options got moved to the top of my structure menu in the admin panel, specifically the "add view," "add view from template," and "import" are all at the top of the structure menu over blocks. There's no obvious way to change this in menu management, so I'm not sure what happened and how to undo this?
[image]